# Python: TypeError while using os.environ.get

Tags: python, windows, bash

I want to access a shell environment variable in my python script.
I am trying this

```
import os
print os.environ.get["HOME"]
```

I get this error when I am executing in python 
(I am getting the same error in bash also)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sraparim\Desktop\GitHub issues\issue #1187\test.py", line 54, in <module>
    print os.environ.get["HOME"]
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\sraparim\Desktop\GitHub issues\issue #1187\test.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\sraparim\Desktop\GitHub issues\issue #1187]
[path: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\OSD-ShellApplications;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SoftphoneSDK\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27;C:\Python27]
```

Please help...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`get()` is a method on the `environ` object; use parentheses instead of brackets:

```
print os.environ.get('HOME')
```

or brackets without `get`, which [implicitly calls `__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__):

```
print os.environ['HOME']
```